# ssh-add -lの結果がThe agent has no identities.なのにSSHでログインできるのはなぜ？

Tags: ssh, openssh

この状態でSSHにどうしてログインできるのか不気味に思っています
まず、

```
$ ssh-add -K .ssh/id_rsa
```

を実行してSSH接続用のキーを登録しました
これにより無事にSSHサーバに接続はできました
しかし、PC・Macを再起動後ssh-add -Lを実行すると

```
takayamanorikonoiMac:~ takayamanoriko$ ssh-add -L
The agent has no identities.
```

何も登録されていない状態になっていました
それにもかかわらず、sshコマンドでは依然として接続できました
(なお、SSHの接続先はBitbucketなので、サーバ側の設定ミスはまずないと思います)

そこで教えていただきたいのですが、なぜログインできるのだと思いますか？
また、The agent has no identities.の結果でもキーは登録されたままなのですか？
その他、調べた方が良さそうな点、勘違いしていそうなことがあれば教えていただけると助かります

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 2):

- [OpenSSH-7.3p1 日本語マニュアルページ](https://euske.github.io/openssh-jman/ssh.html)

> -i identityファイル
>       公開鍵認証の際にidentity (秘密鍵) を読むファイルを指定します。デフォルトは、プロトコル 1 の場合ユーザのホームディレクトリにある~/.ssh/identity、**プロトコル 2 の場合は~/.ssh/id_dsa ,~/.ssh/id_ecdsa ,~/.ssh/id_ed25519および~/.ssh/id_rsaになっています。** identity ファイルは設定ファイルによって、ホストごとに指定することもできます。複数の-i オプションを指定することも可能です。(設定ファイルで複数の鍵を指定することもできます。)証明書がCertificateFile設定項目で明示的に指定されていない場合、ssh は末尾に-cert.pubのついたファイル名からも証明書を読み込もうとします。

要は、`$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` ファイルはデフォルトで使用する秘密鍵なので、特に指定しなくても(`ssh-add`で追加しなくても)使用されます。